# jpa many to many search query(not in clause)

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

Article

```java
@Entity
public class Article {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
    private UUID id;
    private String title;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String content;
    private Date createdAt;
    private Date updatedAt;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
    @JoinTable(name = "article_tag", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "article_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id"))
    private Set<Tag> tag = new HashSet<>();
    private String source;
```

Tag

```java
@Entity
public class Tag {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
    private UUID id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tag")
    private Set<Article> article = new HashSet<>();
    private Date createdAt;
    private Date updatedAt;
```

When receiving a set of tag.name(maybe 2 or 3 or more tags), find out the articles which fit all the tag.name.(so In clause is not the answer)

Is there any JSQL way to achieve this or any effencial way?thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT article.* FROM article INNER JOIN (SELECT article_tag.article_id,COUNT(article_tag.tag_id) as tag_num FROM article_tag LEFT JOIN tag ON tag.id = article_tag.tag_id WHERE tag.`name` IN('tag1','tag2') GROUP BY article_id HAVING tag_num = TAGNUM) AS result ON article.id = result.article_id
```

Tunrs out it can be done with the sql above, where the TAGNUM and IN clause can be dynamic filled with program.

article_tag is middle table.

We only pick the count that fit the size of our tag list, which means fit the whole list. And then we get the result we want.